# Source activate does not do anything

Tags: environment-variables, anaconda, git-bash

When I try to activate my environment (which has worked before), nothing happens. Is the only way to fix this is reinstalling everything? I have tried changing environment variables etc, but nothing works.

[image]

Comment: What does `which activate` show? Are you running `conda` for `windows` or `conda` for `cygwin`?

Comment: @alvits Based on the prompt, it could be `mingw` :P

Comment: What is the output for `env | grep -e CONDA -e PS1`?

Comment: `which activate` outputs `/c/Users/keirp/Miniconda3/Scripts/activate`

Comment: It outputs `PS1=\[\033]0;$TITLEPREFIX:${PWD//[^[:ascii:]]/?}\007\]\n\[\033[32m\]\u@\h \[\[35m\]$MSYSTEM \[\033[33m\]\w\[\033[36m\]\`__git_ps1\`\[\033[0m\]\n$`

Answer (score 4):

You can have more clues with `conda info --envs`

> Environments are installed by default into the envs directory in your conda directory.

Note: **In Windows it is good practice to deactivate one environment before activating another**.

If source activate does not set the environment variables properly, [you can set them manually](https://conda.io/docs/using/envs.html#saved-environment-variables)

See also [troubleshooting](https://conda.io/docs/troubleshooting.html#issue-shell-commands-open-from-wrong-location):

> Reactivate the environment or run `hash -r` (in bash) or `rehash` (in zsh)
>
> When you run `source activate`, conda automatically runs `hash -r` in bash and `rehash` in zsh to clear the hashed commands, so conda will find things in the new path on the `PATH`.
>
> This is a relatively rare problem, since this will only happen if you activate an environment or use the root environment, run a command from somewhere else, then conda install a program and try to run the program again without running source activate or source deactivate.
>
> The command `type command_name` will always tell you exactly what is being run (this is better than which command_name, which ignores hashed commands and searches the `PATH` directly), and `hash -r` (in bash) or `rehash` (in zsh) will reset the hash, or you can run `source activate`.

---

Finally, note there are [issues with Cygwin or MsysGit bash](https://github.com/conda/conda/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=activate%20does%20not%20work%20windows&type=Issues):

- [issue 3352](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/3352#issuecomment-243563248): Cygwin activate works incorrectly
- [issue 1429](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/1429): Windows Msysgit Bash shell cannot run conda's `activate.bat`

Comment: `conda info --envs` has the same output as `conda-env list`. Activating/deactivating my environment does not change the output of that command. I tried `hash -r`. If I try `source activate` on some wrong environment name, it errors, but it does not error when I use an environment that exists. I also tried uninstalling git (and git bash along with it) and reinstalling, as well as anaconda. None of these worked.

Comment: @KeiranPaster are the issues mentioned relevant?

Comment: Doesn't seem like it.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the command prompt is set to show the name of the active environment. To disable this option:

`conda config --set changeps1 false`

To re-enable this option:

`conda config --set changeps1 true`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, probably you've messed with some configurations ( same thing I did trying to learn how to use ubuntu )

Anyway it may not show you (base) or (env-name) at the beginning of the line and does nothing when you run `conda activate env-name` but it actually does activate it.

You can ensure that by running `conda env list` which will list all your envs, and an * in front of your current activated env

there should be a way to restore everything to normal I think but I don't know how for the moment, will update my reply if I figure it out.